# What is recommended prerequisite knowledge to get kid started with Create 2?

Tags: irobot-create

What aged children is the Create 2 appropriate for?  What is prerequisite knowledge?  Is this an appropriate first robot kit for a child?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "probably not".  The long answer depends on the abilities of you and your child.

Create 2 allows you to plug the robot into a computer via USB and interact with it through serial commands.  Many 3rd parties have created interfaces for this, some of which are in Python, (for example [PyRobot](http://code.google.com/p/pyrobot/)).  Your child may be able to handle this depending on grade level.  This is probably the lowest bar to entry.

If you take a look at the Create 2 [sample projects](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx), you should be able to get a feel for the prerequisite knowledge required for other (perhaps more interesting) projects.  For example, can your child solder and hook up an Arduino?

That being said, as a robotics scientist, my 5.5 year old son has been around robots and technology from a very young age.  I plan on doing some Create projects with him.  Although I fully expect to do all the work.